# How can I create a global variable and make it available to all views in ASP.NET MVC 5 framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application that is written on the top of the ASP.NET MVC 5 framework.

I created a base controller where all of my controllers inheres. My base controller looks like this

```
[Authorize]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected IFlashManager Flash { get; set; }
    protected ICookie Cookie { get; set; }
    protected ICacheClient Cache { get; set; }

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        Cookie = new CookieJar(requestContext.HttpContext);
        Flash = new FlashManager(TempData);
        Cache = new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(new NewtonsoftSerializer());
    }
}
```

I want to make the `Cookie` and `Cache` objects available globally to all of my views.

Microsoft have done the same thing with the `User` object.

Is there a way I can do this without using `ViewBag` or `TempData`?

Comment: you can use Session, assign once and the objects will be there till the session expires

Comment: What kind of `User` object said here? If the cookie & cache data is divided per-user basis, usage of `Session` variable is enough.

Comment: What about creating an abstract ViewModel that holds the `Cookie` and `Cache` property? Every other ViewModel must inherit that abstract ViewModel and add it's additional properties. That way you could say that your @model is that abstract ViewModel you created.

Answer (score 2):

I created a new class that inherits from `WebViewPage<T>`.

- Provide a property for each new thing you want to make available.
- Override the `InitHelpers()` to initialize these properties.
- Configure the system to use your class instead of `WebViewPage<T>`

VB example:

```
Imports System.Linq.Expressions

Public Class ProjectMvcViewPage(Of T)
    Inherits WebViewPage(Of T)


    Public Overrides Sub InitHelpers()

        MyBase.InitHelpers()

        Framework = New FrameworkHelper(Of T)(MyBase.ViewContext, Me)

    End Sub



    Public Overrides Sub Execute()

    End Sub



    Public Overloads Property Framework As FrameworkHelper(Of T)


End Class

Public Class ProjectMvcViewPage
    Inherits ProjectMvcViewPage(Of Object)

End Class




Public Class FrameworkHelper(Of T)
    Inherits HtmlHelper(Of T)

    Public Sub New(ByVal viewContext As ViewContext, ByVal viewDataContainer As IViewDataContainer)
        MyBase.New(viewContext, viewDataContainer)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal viewContext As ViewContext, ByVal viewDataContainer As IViewDataContainer, ByVal routeCollection As RouteCollection)
        MyBase.New(viewContext, viewDataContainer, routeCollection)
    End Sub



    '   TODO:   Framework-specific methods

End Class

Public Class FrameworkHelper
    Inherits AkcHtmlHelper(Of Object)

    Public Sub New(ByVal viewContext As ViewContext, ByVal viewDataContainer As IViewDataContainer)
        MyBase.New(viewContext, viewDataContainer)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal viewContext As ViewContext, ByVal viewDataContainer As IViewDataContainer, ByVal routeCollection As RouteCollection)
        MyBase.New(viewContext, viewDataContainer, routeCollection)
    End Sub

End Class
```

... and register it in Web.config

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <!--<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">-->
    <pages pageBaseType="Project.ProjectMvcViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("foo", "bar");
HttpContext.Session.GetString("foo");
```